# How to set the Headers.$ input for Step functions to invoke api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

When I used the step function to invoke API Gateway, I filled the "Headers.$": "$.input.headers", but when I test it, it gives me `could not be used to start the Task: [The value of the field 'Headers' has an invalid format]` every time,
I tried this

```
"input": {
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "abcd",
            "Content-Type": "application-json"
        }
    }
```

it doesn't work, could anyone give me an example of this headers field?

Really appreciate!

Comment: I just find out AWS doesn't support `Authorization` header, so I think the question becomes to how can I pass the `Authorization` header to API Gateway?

Answer (score 5):

I met same problem. And I resolved it as following.

First, we cannot use `Authorization` header and other some headers as [the note of this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html#connect-api-gateway-requests-optional). So we should use a custom header. It is mapped to `Authorization` header in API Gateway.

Next, from what I've tried, we probably should use array format in value of `Headers`.
So you can write as following:

```
"input": {
  "headers": {
    "x-Authorization": ["abcd"],
    "Content-Type": ["application-json"]
  }
}
```

and I use [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) as following:

```
"Headers":{
  "x-Authorization.$":"States.Array(States.Format('Bearer {}', $.SecretOutput.Token))"
}
```

And finally, we should set two configration in API Gateway.

1. Set request parameter mapping to map `method.request.header.x-Authorization` to `Authorization` header. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters)
2. Set accepting custom request header `x-Authorization`. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html#setup-method-request-parameters)

Comment: but will the cognito authorizer work with this authorization header?